# Is there any way to switch off the highlighting of links in pdfXeLaTeX?

Tags: xetex, hyperref, highlighting

Because this doesn't do it for me:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[pdfhighlight=/N]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{test}
\end{document}
```

If I process it with pdfLaTeX then the on-click-highlighting gets switched off as expected. (Tested in Acrobat Reader DC 2017.012.20098.)

I also tried passing the option via `\hypersetup`, but that made no difference.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Wherefrom? I can't find a package by that name anywhere. `hyperref` has an environment by that name, but that switches off the links completely. I still want the links to work, I just don't want them to change colour when I click them.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `nohyperref`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks, but that switches off all links. I still want them to show, I just don't want them to invert when clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The required code, present in other drivers, is missing at various places in `hxetex.def`. This patch should add it and render changes of the PDF highlighting (option `pdfhighlight`) functional:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[pdfhighlight=/N]{hyperref}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\usepackage{ifxetex}
\ifxetex
  \let\Hy@setpdfborderOrig\Hy@setpdfborder
  \def\Hy@setpdfborder{
    \ifx\@pdfhightlight\@empty
    \else
      /H\@pdfhighlight
    \fi
    \Hy@setpdfborderOrig
  }
\fi
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great stuff, that does it, thanks! In an ideal world, this should come as part of the `hyperref` installation ...

Comment: I guess the authors simply forgot it to add. You can file a bug report, if you wish: https://github.com/ho-tex/hyperref/issues

Comment: [Just did](https://github.com/ho-tex/hyperref/issues/40), thanks.